# Create a list of integers with duplicate values in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, integer

This question will no doubt to a piece of cake for a Python 2.7 expert (or enthusiast), so here it is.

How can I create a list of integers whose value is duplicated next to it's original value like this?

```
a = list([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])
```

It's really easy to do it like this:

```
for i in range(10): a.append(int(i / 2))
```

But i'd rather have it in one simple line starting a = *desired output.*

Thank you for taking the time to answer.

PS. none of the "**Questions that may already have your answer** were what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> [i//2 for i in xrange(10)]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

A simple generic approach:

```
>>> f = lambda rep, src: reduce(lambda l, e: l+rep*[e], src, [])
>>> f(2, xrange(5))
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
>>> f(3, ['a', 'b'])
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

Comment: Was going to add that it would be `[int(i/2) for i in range(10)]` in Python 3, but the question is for 2.7, so adding as a comment.

Comment: Couldn't both 2.7 and 3.0 just use `i//2` ?

Comment: Fair enough, I hadn't thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> sorted(2*range(5))
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a technique that works on any list, not just `int` lists, and doesn't rely on the (relatively) expensive `sorted()` function. It also lets you specify the number of repetitions.

First, a simple version to solve the problem in the OP:

```
print [u for v in [[i,i] for i in range(5)] for u in v]
```

**output**

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

And now the fancy (but slightly more readable) version.

```
a = list('abcde')
rep = 3
print [item for sublist in [rep * [i] for i in a] for item in sublist]
```

**output**

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

---

Here's an expanded version of the previous example, written using simple `for` loops rather than as a nested list comprehension.

```
b = []
for sublist in [rep * [i] for i in a]:
    for item in sublist:
        b.append(item)
print b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted( range(10)  +  range(10) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sorted(map(str, range(0,5) + range(0,5)))
['0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(i/2 )for i in range(10)]
```

or

```
[i//2 for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover the specific case asked in the question, but if you want to duplicate the contents of an arbitrary list, you can use the following:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [1, 'a', 3]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(l,l)))
[1, 1, 'a', 'a', 3, 3]
```